# Automating registration flow using Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am new to web driver. I am supposed to test a registration form using selenium2. I am being told to use functional testing to test the form. I have to make tests like(enter username, password, confirm password and click on terms and conditions and only then the create account button gets enabled.I have to enter invalid username, password less than the specified length and for each test I have to assert if the create account button gets enabled.) Checked about functional testing but couldn't get the right information for my issue.
Appreciate help on this

Thanks
Java Beginner.

Comment: Stack Overflow is really more suited for specific questions, once you've tried a few things and gotten stuck. As it stands, now, you'll probably get more help searching Google or Youtube for things like "selenium webdriver tutorial".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields which are present in the website are called as WebElements.

In Selenium, you can find the element and write string by using the code:

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("your field ID"));
username.sendKeys("your value");
```

You can do the same thing for the password. Try using dataProvider concept in TestNG to pass different types of values to the same function.

Answer (score 0):

For simple tests try Selenium IDE. Then select "Options -> Clipboard Format -> Java/Junit 4/Webdriver". Copy all the html code and paste in the framework you're using. It will allow you to understand basic workflow and syntax of the application.